# Как нарисовать такую фигуру на css?

Tags: css

Как нарисовать такую фигуру на css?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: прямоугольник с треугольником-то?)

Answer (score 7):

Как вариант.

```css
body {
  background: #ccc;
}

.flag {
  display: block;
  width: 135px;
  height: 135px;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0 #999;
}

.flag::after,
.flag::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 95px;
  height: 95px;
  background: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(45deg);
  z-index: -1;
}

.flag::after {
  box-shadow: inherit;
}

.flag::before {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="flag"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Например как-то так. Тени можно сделать через box-shadow свойства.

```css
.flag {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}

.flag::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -50px;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-top: 50px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="flag"></div>
```

Comment: Только они не сделаются для `:after`.